# Azure Maps - detect zoom direction

Tags: azure-maps

When zoomed, the map invokes zoomstart, zoom and zoomend events. Is there a way to tell if the map is zooming in our out?  Really at zoomend, I need to understand if the map was zoomed in our out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code accomplishes this...

```
var currentZoomLevel;

map.events.add('zoomstart', layer, function (e) { currentZoomLevel = map.getCamera().zoom; })
map.events.add('zoomend', layer, function (e) {
    if (currentZoomLevel > map.getCamera().zoom) {
        // zoomed out
    }
})
```